# Django Rest Framewrok api how to add Authecation permission for all

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework

I've followed tutorial provided here exactly. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/

But all my snippets are being viewed even there is no log in. How to prevent this? I've user this in the settings.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
}
```

> And now the Users api is not giving access.

[image: here]

> But snippets are getting viewed.

[image: here]

I'm new to Django, how can I add permission for snippets to, to act like user. Also I want admin to be able to edit, delete snippets. how to accomplish these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add to you view this code:

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class SnippetListCreateView(ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticated
    ]
```